# Is it a good Idea to add an Event to *everything* related to a given record?

Tags: rest-api, rest

I'm building an app where I'll log an event that an email was opened to Leads and Contacts that match that email address. I'm wondering how many times this Event should be duplicated.

Does it make sense to also duplicate the Event to the Accounts and Opportunities related to those Leads and Contacts? I know that Salesforce users have different ways of managing their data, so does it make sense to kind of litter that Event everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Event (Activity) can only have one related "What" object so you will need to choose whether that related object is an opportunity, account, campaign, or whatever. This relationship is mapped through the polymorphic WhatId field on Event, and you only get that one field for one relationship.

Comment: I know that, but you can specify a WhatId or a WhoId for the related object. I'm saying I'd **duplicate** the Event for a Contact into its related Account records and then **again** to its related Opportunity records. And I'm wondering whether it makes sense to do that. Do Salesforce users usually duplicate Events across all related records?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend duplicating events, no. That would paint a misleading picture of the count of events for a given person, should you wish to report on that information.

Comment: That's what I figured. So it better if I just keep it on the Lead or Contact? Is that scope too narrow or should it be on related Account or Opportunity?

Comment: If that event is relevant to the Account or Opp, then it makes sense to fill in the WhatId with that object. I guess it depends on the your business use case as to whether or not it makes sense to associate the event to those objects.

Comment: If the event has something to do with winning the money, then it makes sense to associate to opp. If the event is related to the org, then it makes sense to associate to account.